# How dynamically generate menu options for <select> from an array using React.CreateElement()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Here is the code for generating the options manually. Is there anyway to populate the options dynamically from an array or json

```
    return React.createElement("select", {},
      React.createElement("option", {value: "A"}, "Option A"),
      React.createElement("option", {value: "B"}, "Option B"),
      React.createElement("option", {value: "C"}, "Option C")
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend compiling JSX, and you can easily use `.map` where the callback returns a component:

```
const values = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
// ...
return (
  <select>
    {values.map(val => <option value={val}>{val}</option>)}
  </select>
);
```

If you can't use JSX (though you really should for anything remotely serious, since it makes syntax much easier), you can spread the result into `createElement` instead.

```
return React.createElement("select", {},
  ...values.map(value => React.createElement("option", { value }, value))
);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the insanely fast reply. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
const values = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
// ...
return (
  <select>
    {values.map((val, i) => <option key={i} value={val}>{val}</option>)}
  </select>
);
```

Don't forget to add key prop as React will complain about it